# Instalar una librería de python para una versión especifica

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, pip, modulos

He instalado mediante consola el módulo ggplot pero parece que lo está instalando para python 3.8.2 y lo necesito para la 3.7.3. Alguna idea de como lo puedo hacer?

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\python\3-regresionlogistica.py in 
     23 from sklearn import metrics
     24 from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
---> 25 from ggplot import *
     26 
     27 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ggplot'
```

Comment: ¿qué comando exacto utilizaste para instalar?

Comment: he probado "pip install ggplot" "pip3.7 install ggplot". También lo he intentado instalar en anaconda porque estoy usando las extensiones de jupyter para vscode pero no me ha funcionado

Comment: qué comando usas para ejecutar tu archivo `.py`? la respuesta de abulafia debería servirte

Answer (score 3):

La forma garantizada de que un paquete se quede instalado para una versión concreta de python es instalarlo con el propio intérprete python, usando el módulo `pip`.

Estos serían los pasos:

1. Asegúrate de que sabes cómo ejecutar el intérprete python en la versión que te interesa.

   Para ello prueba `python --version` y verifica que lo que sale es la versión para la cual quieres instalar el paquete. Por ejemplo:

   ```
   python --version
   Python 3.7.3
   ```

   Si no sale así la versión que querías, puedes especificar la ruta completa hacia el intérprete deseado. Si no conoces cuál es esa ruta deberás buscarla de algún modo, pero eso depende del operativo.
2. Usa ese intérprete para instalar el módulo deseado usando el comando:

   ```
   python -m pip install ggplot
   ```

En todo caso, te recomiendo que uses entornos virtuales para mantener las cosas separadas y no liarte. Usando entornos virtuales tienes que:

1. Crear el entorno usando `python -m venv nombre_carpeta`. Al igual que antes debes asegurarte que el python que estás ejecutando es el de la versión correcta. Esto creará una carpeta con el `nombre_carpeta` que le hayas dado. Dentro de ella habrá una instalación "local" de esa versión de python. Puedes usar este comando muchas veces para crear múltiples carpetas (por si en cada una de esas "instalaciones locales" deseas instalar paquetes diferentes).

   Se recomienda crear todas estas diferentes carpetas bajo la carpeta `venvs` en tu directorio de usuario, para tenerlas todas localizadas y para que los diferentes IDEs que soportan los entornos virtuales sepan dónde encontrarlas.
2. "Activar" ese entorno. Eso consiste en ejecutar un script que hay dentro de la carpeta así creada. El nombre del script depende de si estás en Unix o windows.

   En Unix sería:

   ```
   source nombre_carpeta/bin/activate
   ```

   En Windows (desde una terminal CMD) sería:

   ```
   nombre_carpeta\Scripts\activate.bat
   ```

   En Windows usando powershell sería:

   ```
   nombre_carpeta\Scripts\activate.ps1
   ```
3. Una vez tienes el entorno "activado" tu Prompt cambia para recordarte que estás trabajando en ese entorno. Dentro de la terminal en la que tienes activado el entorno, cuando pongas `python` se ejecutará el python de ese entorn. Cuando pongas `pip` se ejecutará el pip de ese entorno y lo que instale lo hará en ese entorno.
4. De modo que basta ahora poner `pip install ggplot` con ese entorno activado. Y de la misma forma puedes instalar cualquier otro paquete que necesites.

Todos los paquetes así instalados serán "locales" de ese entorno (estarán instalados en la carpeta `nombre_carpeta` que hayas usado). Para poder usarlos debes recordar siempre activar el entorno de nuevo antes de ejecutar cualquier programa que requiera esos paquetes.

La ventaja es que no "contaminas" el python de sistema instalando cosas en él. Puedes tener tantos entornos virtuales como necesites, cada uno con diferentes paquetes instalados e incluso con diferente versión de python (la versión será la del intérprete que usaste al poner `python -m venv nombre_carpeta`

Comment: Lo he intentado pero me sigue sin ir. Es posible que tenga un pip para cada version? y si es así como uso cada pip

Comment: Precisamente porque es posible que hay un pip diferente para cada versión es por lo que en mi respuesta te aconsejo no usar pip. Si te fijas lo que uso para instalar es directamente python con la opción  `-m pip`. Eso instala los paquetes para el mismo python que usaste al hacerlo. Simplemente asegúrate de que es el python correcto el que ejecutas con la opción `-m pip`